# Error writing a query with multiple associations using ActiveRecord query methods in RubyOnRails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I'm having trouble writing a query using RubyOnRails ActiveRecord query methods. I have the following model associatinons:

Order many-to-many OrderProduct many-to-many Product one-to-many ProductLocation

What I want is get all Orders which Product Locations have name = 'something' (name is a column in ProductLocation table)

How can I archive this? Currently I have this

```rb
Order.joins(order_products: [{product: :product_location}]).select('orders.*, product_locations.name as location').where(product_locations: {name: 'NY'})
```

but it throws an error

```sql
SELECT COUNT(orders.*, product_locations.name as location) FROM "orders" INNER JOIN "order_products" ON "order_products"."order_id" = "orders"."id" INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."id" = "order_products"."product_id" INNER JOIN "product_locations" ON "product_locations"."id" = "products"."product_location_id" WHERE "product_locations"."name" = 'NY'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(orders.*, product_locations.name as location) F...
```

what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `COUNT(orders.*, product_locations.name as location)` is wrong. What are you trying to do ?, change it to something like: `... COUNT(orders.*) as orders_count, product_locations.name as location FROM...`

Comment: The error is coming from `.select('orders.*, product_locations.name as location')` and I don't see why you would need that. You can see in the output `COUNT(orders.*, product_locations.name as location)` will never work in PSQL. Try it without it and see if you get an error.